# How can I display tabs as characters?

Tags: whitespace, tab-characters

When I work on files in python, I sometimes mistake tabs for spaces and vice versa. Is there a way I can get Vim to display a character for a tab instead of a tab?

Comment: Just as a side note, you can configure to convert all tabs to spaces with `retab` every time you save the file.

Comment: If you have installed [vim-faq](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim_faq), you can get an offline answer there: `:h vim-faq` and search `/invisible`. The hard to memorize tag is [`:h faq-19.8`](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-19.8).

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Yes, use listchars:

```
set list
set listchars=tab:>-
```

If you put these two lines in your .vimrc, tabs will be shown as `>` for the start position and `-` through the rest of the tab.

(Sidenote: listchars can also show trailing spaces with `trail:x` (replace `x` with the character you want to use for a trailing space), which can be useful as well.)

Comment: Note: I like to use `set listchars=tab:!·,trail:·`, IMHO `·` is a lot clearer than a `-` ... You need a fairly recent Vim version for this to work btw (not sure which exactly, I think 7.3.x)...

Comment: I like using the unicode character `▸` as it is slightly smaller than `>`. Currently I see trailing white space by marking the eol (though I may try the above). My settings are: `set listchars=eol:¬,tab:▸\ ` and

Comment: This one works the best for me `set listchars=eol:·,tab:⍿·,trail:×·` as it is very clean.

Comment: Here's what I'm currently using: `set listchars=tab:┌┬┐,trail:·`. (The non-ASCII characters are: 250c:BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DOWN AND RIGHT, 252c:BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DOWN AND HORIZONTAL, 2510:BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DOWN AND LEFT, b7:MIDDLE DOT.)

Comment: I note that with vim 8.2, not all Unicode chars are legal apparently, I was messing around with using some odd ones like `trail:﹍` and it blew up. Not sure what the limits are for these things...

Comment: FYI you can get ▸ by typing `<c-k>PR` (see `:help digraph`)

Comment: I suggest using `⸱` instead of `·` , that is U+2E31 WORD SEPARATOR MIDDLE DOT as it appears less squarrish in the terminal. I still would like to find an even smaller dot though.

Answer (score 79):

The basic answer is `:set list`, which causes tabs to display as `^I`.

However, I recommend going beyond that.  Just `:set list` is problematic in that it fails to preserve visual alignment on screen.  For example:

```
%.o: %.cpp
^Ig++ -c $<
```

doesn't look good, especially when you expect the `g` of `g++` to appear under the first `p` of `cpp` (assuming `tabstop=8`).

Therefore, I suggest that in your `.vimrc` you put something like `:set listchars=tab:␉·`  (To be clear, that's Unicode character [U+2409 SYMBOL FOR HORIZONTAL TABULATION](https://codepoints.net/U+2409) followed by [U+00B7 MIDDLE DOT](https://codepoints.net/U+00B7).)

As explained in [`:help listchars`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27listchars%27), a two-character setting for `tab:xy` causes visual alignment to be preserved:

> ```
> tab:xy        Two characters to be used to show a tab.  The first
>               char is used once.  The second char is repeated to
>               fill the space that the tab normally occupies.
>               "tab:>-" will show a tab that takes four spaces as
>               ">---".  When omitted, a tab is show as ^I.
> ```

The example above would appear on screen as:

```
%.o: %.cpp
␉·······g++ -c $<
```

---

Personally, I go all-out with my `listchars`:

```
:set listchars=eol:⏎,tab:␉·,trail:␠,nbsp:⎵
```

- For `eol`, I use [U+23CE RETURN SYMBOL](https://codepoints.net/U+23CE)
- For `trail`, I use [U+2420 SYMBOL FOR SPACE](https://codepoints.net/U+2420)
- For `nbsp`, I use [U+23B5 BOTTOM SQUARE BRACKET](https://codepoints.net/U+23B5)

These characters are distinctive enough that they rarely appear literally in document text.

To type these special characters into your `vimrc`, type <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>`23CE` while in Insert Mode, as explained in [`:help utf-8-typing`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/mbyte.txt.html#utf-8-typing).

Comment: See also `set lcs=tab:├─`

Comment: this just gave me a ? at eol

Answer (score 38):

## Highlighting tabs

### Temporary <kbd>Tab</kbd> highlighting

For occasional use, one can simply highlight all tabs in a document using the following search `/` command:

```
/\t
```

To remove the highlighting, simply type `:noh` which is short for `:nohlsearch` —no high lighting.

### Permanent <kbd>Tab</kbd> highlighting

```
" Highlight tabs as errors.
" https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9353/3168
match Error /\t/
```

[image: Tab highlighting in vim]

### More highlighting

For more of these useful highlighting commands —including combined with trailing whitespace and making this permanent— see the [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces).

Comment: You can also use `:match Error /\t/` to highlight tabs (or any other pattern for that matter) independently from the search register and hlsearch (type `:match` to clear it).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker One can find a whole lot more of these useful highlighting commands (including combined with trailing whitespace!) on the [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces) about [highlighting unwanted spaces](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces).

Answer (score 10):

I personally like the use of the plugin [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine), which displays a vertical line at indentation levels.

It is of great help especially in python, where the indentation is important.

[image: (Image taken from the link above)]

Among other things, it provides a toggle command, that can be mapped to a key combination, so that you can turn it off, when you don't need it.

Comment: I believe this plugin is intended for spaces indenting though?

Comment: Indeed:

> This plugin is used for displaying thin vertical lines at each indentation level for code indented with spaces. For code indented with tabs I think there is no need to support it, because you can use `:set list lcs=tab:\|\ ` (here is a space).

Comment: indent guide supports tabs as well: https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides

Comment: Is there a way to also display tabs (well i don't want tabs but lines to connect the brackets) in empty lines?

Answer (score 7):

Easiest method is to do `:set list`, which will show tabs as `^I` and end of line as `$`.

I like to use a mapping that calls

```
:set invlist
```

to toggle between regular display and list display.

For example:

```
:nmap <leader>l :set invlist<cr>
```

This allows me to quickly check if there are tab vs space problems and then go back to a regular display.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to show tabs differently in a regular terminal and gvim.

```
set list!
if has('gui_running')
    set listchars=tab:▶\ ,trail:·,extends:\#,nbsp:.
else
    set listchars=tab:>.,trail:.,extends:\#,nbsp:.
endif
```

(Adding for completeness, in case others find it useful).

Answer (score 5):

This can be easily achieved using `listchars` by specifying the tab as: `,tab:\ \ ┊,`

By providing **two** escaped spaces in *front* of your `tab` declaration, `vim` will repeat the spaces. This is opposed to the default, where vim prefers the second character as the repeating character.

This achieves a similar effect to using a plugin like `IndentLine` without the overhead. Here's an example of what it might look like using the following complete `listchars` config:

```
set listchars=eol:↓,tab:\ \ ┊,trail:●,extends:…,precedes:…,space:·
```

[image: source code]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Do note that the top 2 answers (and a few of the others as well) already mention this solution.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you for the friendly welcome and feedback! However, I disagree. This is an alternative to @mike's response. While the other responses do reference `listchars`, none of them explain how to achieve repeating the left character to achieve the same result as a plugin like `IndentLine`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I've reworded my answer to hopefully clarify how my answer differs from the others mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

I combined @john-om approach with this character
[Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936374/is-there-an-invisible-character-that-is-not-regarded-as-whitespace)
and indentLine plugin.
So, if I use spaces, plugin show nice formated indents, if I use tabs, **pipes are the only visible mark** and that is what I want. I can also toggle tab's marks.

```
" indicate tabs
:nmap <leader>l :set invlist<cr>
set list listchars=tab:❘⠀,trail:·,extends:»,precedes:«,nbsp:×
```

Comment: I like this one, it is a lot more cleaner, I just added the eol to the end of it, `set list listchars=tab:❘⠀,extends:»,precedes:«,nbsp:×,eol:⏎`

Answer (score 1):

### I like VSCode's "render whitespace" display

I customize vim's space and tab chars like vscode, i.e. use dark gray color dot for space char, use arrow char for tab.

### My vim configuration

```
"\u21A6 is ⇥
"set listchars=eol:$,tab:⇥¬¬,trail:·,extends:>,precedes:<,space:·
" 0x1F862 is 
" https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/422/displaying-tabs-as-characters
set listchars=tab:\ ,trail:·,extends:>,precedes:<,space:·
" Set the list char color
" https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6136/how-to-dim-characters-from-set-list/6140#6140
" :hi SpecialKey ctermfg=grey guifg=grey50
" https://gist.github.com/morumo/9405368
:hi SpecialKey ctermfg=darkgray guifg=gray70
```

[image]

[image]

### My emacs configuration

Btw, I also tried to configure the render display in my emacs configuration:

```
;; https://github.com/jameshintaro/.emacs/
;;http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/whitespace-mode.html
(require 'whitespace)
(setq whitespace-style
      '(face tabs tab-mark spaces space-mark))

(setq whitespace-display-mappings
      '(
        (space-mark ?\u3000 [?□])  ; 全角スペース
        (space-mark ?\u0020 [?\xB7])  ; 半角スペース
        (newline-mark ?\n   [?$ ?\n]) ; 改行記号
        ;(tab-mark   ?\t   [?\x2192 ?\t]) ; tab
    (tab-mark   ?\t   [?\x1F862 ?\t]) ; tab
        ) )

(setq whitespace-space-regexp "\\([\x0020\x3000]+\\)" )

;(set-face-foreground 'whitespace-space "Goldenrod1")
(set-face-foreground 'whitespace-space "Azure4")
(set-face-background 'whitespace-space 'nil)
(set-face-bold-p 'whitespace-space t)

;;(set-face-foreground 'whitespace-tab "DarkOliveGreen1")
(set-face-foreground 'whitespace-tab "Azure4")
(set-face-background 'whitespace-tab nil)
(set-face-underline  'whitespace-tab t)

;;(set-face-foreground 'whitespace-newline  "DimGray")
;;(set-face-background 'whitespace-newline 'nil)
```

Which looks like the following:
[image]

[image]

Comment: 10x, was really missing that